# When add command line support to my Winforms app Is it better to use same EXE file or add new console application project?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

I try to add command line support to my `Winforms` application so i changed this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
    else
    {

    }         
}
```

But i try to return string to the user in case the user insert the command `MyExeFile.exe help` to show the user all the command line options and i don't know how so i wonder maybe it's better to use other `EXE` file ?

Comment: Don't return a string, Use Console.WriteLine, etc to output to console.

Comment: Can i open Console window from Winforms ? i try and it didn't work

Comment: Change your project output settings to console and it will.

Comment: But now when open my GUI i can see the console... any way to change it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could see if the arguments contains "help". If it does, display a message to the user and then exit the app before loading the main form.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.ToList().Contains("help"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Help is on the way...");

        return; 
    }

    ...
}
```

You'll need to add the following `using` directive:

```
using System.Linq;
```

---

If you want the help text to appear to show in a `Console` window, just create a form that *looks* like a console window.

Create a new `Form`, with a single `TextBox` in it, and configure the `TextBox`:

- BackColor: Black
- ForeColor: White
- Dock: Fill
- MultiLine: True
- ReadOnly: True
- Text: *Whatever you want to show*

Then show it using:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.ToList().Contains("help"))
    {
        new ConsoleLookalikeForm().ShowDialog();

        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

This took about 2 minutes to make:

[image]

Comment: I don't want message box, i want the option to write to console, is it possible ?